# Data got imported (using PDO) twice when running test with Codeception

Tags: php, csv, codeception

I'm writing a small script to *parse CSV information* and store it in a database.
I'm not using any framework since this is a small project, but I use Codeception to test my code.

Basically what my class Parser does is parsing data from a CSV file, process the data (put it more neatly into arrays) and insert that data.

Below is the method for inserting data:

```
public function insertCategories() {
    // prepare statement
    codecept_debug("entering insertCategories");
    $stmt = $this->dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO `cs_menucategory` (`catid`, `menugroupid`, `categoryname`) VALUES (:catid, :menugroupid, :categoryname)");

    // prepare parameters
    $cats = $this->result['Category'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($cats); $i++) {
        $params = array();
        $params['menugroupid'] = $i+1;
        $params['catid'] = $i+1;
        $params['categoryname'] = $cats[$i];

        // execute statement
        $stmt->execute($params);
    }
}
```

I also wrote a simple unit test for this method using Codeception:

```
class Test extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected function setUp() {}

    protected function tearDown() {}

    // tests
    public function test() {
        $parser = new Parser();
        $parser->run(); 
    }
}
```

in which method run is

```
public function run() {
    $this->createResultArrays();
    $this->getCSVData();

    $this->connectDtb();

    $this->processData();
    $this->insertCategories();
}
```

When I ran this test and checked back in my database, all data got **imported twice**. 
Then I tried to see if the method got called more than once, or if the loop was causing the problem by simply printing out status 'flags', but both weren't the case.

Once I tried PHP interactive mode, however, the code worked just fine, all data got imported once and correctly.

So I ran the test again in debug mode, and here was what was returned:

```
    Vy-Huynhs:MenuDrive VyHuynh$ ./vendor/bin/codecept run unit Test --debug
    Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.5
    Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.22 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

      Group 'failed' is empty, no tests are loaded
      entering insertCategories

    Unit Tests (1) ------------------------------
    Modules: Asserts, \Helper\Unit
    ---------------------------------------------
    Running Test::test... 
      entering insertCategories
    Test::test                             Ok
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ---------------------------------------------


    Time: 225 ms, Memory: 9.50Mb

    OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
    Vy-Huynhs:MenuDrive VyHuynh$
```

I suspect this is what causing the error:

> Group 'failed' is empty, no tests are loaded

Maybe there are some configurations to Codeception that I didn't do correctly.

Below is the content of the CSV file:

```
Group,Category,Item 
Main Menu,Appetizers,Buffalo Wings 
,,Chicken Fingers 
,,French Fries 
,Salad,Caesar Salad 
,,House Salad 
Breakfast Menu,Sandwiches,BLT 
,Drinks,Coffee 
,,Tea
```

and this script tried importing data from the Category column.

Thank you all.